# Picker's configuration is not a valid configuration, Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift5

I am working on new image picker API provided by Apple in WWDC2020 named as PHPicker. I am getting this error when I select the image form the picker second time. First time the code works perfectly. Second time when I click on the button to open the picker, app crashes with the following error. "**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Picker's configuration is not a valid configuration.'**".

```
 @IBAction func addVideo(_ sender: UIButton) {
        presentPicker(filter: .videos)
  }

 private func presentPicker(filter: PHPickerFilter?) {
        var configuration = PHPickerConfiguration(photoLibrary: .shared())
        
        // Set the filter type according to the user’s selection.
        configuration.filter = filter
        // Set the mode to avoid transcoding, if possible, if your app supports arbitrary image/video encodings.
        configuration.preferredAssetRepresentationMode = .current
        // Set the selection behavior to respect the user’s selection order.
        configuration.selection = .ordered
        // Set the selection limit to enable multiselection.
        configuration.selectionLimit = 1
        // Set the preselected asset identifiers with the identifiers that the app tracks.
        configuration.preselectedAssetIdentifiers = selectedAssetIdentifiers
        
        let picker = PHPickerViewController(configuration: configuration)
        picker.delegate = self
        present(picker, animated: true)
    }


func picker(_ picker: PHPickerViewController, didFinishPicking results: [PHPickerResult]) {
        dismiss(animated: true)
        
        let existingSelection = self.selection
        var newSelection = [String: PHPickerResult]()
        for result in results {
            let identifier = result.assetIdentifier!
            newSelection[identifier] = existingSelection[identifier] ?? result
        }
        
        // Track the selection in case the user deselects it later.
        selection = newSelection
        selectedAssetIdentifiers = results.map(\.assetIdentifier!)
        selectedAssetIdentifierIterator = selectedAssetIdentifiers.makeIterator()
        
        if selection.isEmpty {
            displayEmptyImage()
        } else {
            displayImage()
        }
    }
```

I am using the same code that is provide by apple on their website.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phpickerviewcontroller. I just have changed the **selectionLimit** to 1 from 0.

[image: Run time error by compiler]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it is documented (just kidding, it's in a header file) that the `preselectedAssetIdentifiers` property is only valid when `selectionLimit` is greater than 1, which is the default.

Here's an answer from the Apple developer forum for reference: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/705493

Answer (score 1):

There must be a problem with your code.
I've copy-pasted your solution and it works correctly on Simulator (iOS 15.0).

Comment: have you tried with the video and open the picker twice ??

Comment: Yes, my implementation can work each time I click on the button, select an asset and dismiss the picker after selecting.

Comment: Maybe you need to update the original question with full code?

Comment: have you set the configuration.selectionLimit = 1 or 0

Comment: but my code is crashing at presentPicker() function ??

Comment: Using your code 1:1 - my code is not crashing in Simulator on iOS 15.0

Comment: I read a similar problem that iPhPicker may cause issue some time and if the code is copied to other project will resolve the issue. That is happening on our case. Thanks for you help. @ferus

Comment: @QaziAmmar I'm running into this issue as well. Can you link to wherever you saw that copying to a new project might help, or share any other information you've learned about this?

Comment: @NickSloan I need to search again because at that time I found it randomly.